# Stack results of loop for regression results (outreg2)

Tags: stata

I appreciate help for this.
I am doing this exercise: running several regressions on Y1 and x=1, x=2 and x=3. I repeat this for Y2. I want to store everything stacked in a table with 3 cols (variables / results from Y1 / results from Y2).
However, the results are not properly stacked.

I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTVze.png)

But I want this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbdBl.png)

This is my code:

```
eststo clear
local replace replace
foreach dep of varlist c3_family c3_child  {
summarize `dep' if post == 0 & treat == 0
local mean_dep = string(r(mean), "%9.2f")
qui: reg `dep' post##tr##dep_treated , vce(cluster intclu)
    boottest 1.post#1.tr#1.dep_treated, nograph boottype(wild) reps(1000) bootcluster(intclu) nonull level(90)
outreg2 c1* using "results/2023_09_28_day_reg_ihs/T_spillovers_arms.doc", ///
        ctitle(`l`dep'') ///
        word `replace'  bdec(3) sdec(4) nor2 nocons  bracket ///
        depvar keep(1.post#1.tr#1.dep_treated) ///
        addstat("Pre-treatment mean", `mean_dep')
        local replace

forvalues i = 1/3 {
summarize `dep' if post == 0 & treat == 0
local mean_dep = string(r(mean), "%9.2f")
qui: reg `dep' post##`i'.treat##dep_treated  if inlist(treat,0,`i'), vce(cluster intclu)
boottest 1.post#`i'.tr#1.dep_treated, nograph boottype(wild) reps(1000) bootcluster(intclu) nonull level(90)
outreg2 * using "results/2023_09_28_day_reg_ihs/T_spillovers_arms.doc", ///
    ctitle(`l`dep'') ///
    word bdec(3) sdec(4) nor2 nocons bracket `replace'  ///
    depvar keep(1.post#`i'.treat#1.dep_treated) ///
    addstat("Pre-treatment mean", `mean_dep')
    local replace
    }       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Stata is reading your commands as three separate regression loops with a single predictor, rather than a single regression with multiple independent variables.

The problem is this line:

```
qui: reg `dep' post##`i'.treat##dep_treated  if inlist(treat,0,`i'), vce(cluster intclu)
```

You need to rewrite it so that each loop includes all the independent variables that you want to use. A simple way to do this is to create a global macro that summarizes all your independent variables and then incorporate the global measure into your loop code. See this Stata page for more info:

https://www.stata.com/manuals/pmacro.pdf